# How to formally prove two formulas are asymptotically equivalent?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, asymptotics, equivalence

I have **two formulas** about variance estimation of linear combination of order statistics given order statistics $X_{1}\leqslant X_{2} \leqslant ...\leqslant X_{n} $ from a random sample of arbitrary distribution. My simulation in R already shows that the two are asymptotically equivalent for lots of cases.But I still need to prove them formally. The two formulas are

$F_{1}(X)$=$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=2}^{n}\sum_{j=2}^{n}\left( a_{0}+a_{1}\left ( \frac{i-1}{n} \right )\right)\left ( a_{0}+a_{1}\left ( \frac{j-1}{n} \right )\right)\left ( \frac{min(i-1,j-1)}{n}-\frac{(i-1)(j-1)}{n^2} \right )\left ( X_{i}-X_{i-1} \right )\left(X_{j}-X_{j-1} \right ),$

$F_{2}(X)$=$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left ( a_{0}X_{k}+a_{1}X_{k}\frac{k}{n}+a_{1}\sum_{i=k}{n}X_{i}\frac{1}{n}-a_{0}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i} -2a_{1}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\frac{i}{n}\right )^2.$

where $a_{0}, a_{1}$ are just arbitrary fixed coeficients.

It is very time consuming to compare them term by term but I already did a large part of it. Anyone else may have some other ideas about how to prove the two formulas are asymptotically the same?

Comment: Did you try to show that their ratio converges to a constant; that is to show $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{F_1(n)}{F_2(n)} = K$ where $K \neq 0$ is a constant?

Comment: @Sobi, hi Sobi,  my simulations in R shows that they converge to 1. But can numerical study account for formal argument of proof ? I find it not so easy to compare term by term. I have tried to compare the coefficients of them term by term , for which I mean coefficients of $ X_{i}^2 $ ....etc. I am just not sure what accounts for a formal proof. thx

Comment: Correction to my first comment: you need to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{F1(n)}{F2(n)}=1$. There might be different ways to do this, but, any formal proof should imply that the ratio goes to 1. I also can't see an easy way to prove the problem, but, showing experimentally that the two sequences are equivalent does not count as a formal proof. Good luck!

Comment: A minor point but should the summations start at 2 rather than 1 in $F_{1}(X)$ because of the use of $X_{i-1}$ and $X_{j-1}$ ?

Comment: @JimBaldwin, yes , you are correct because of the approximation.

Comment: I wonder if instead of showing $\lim_{n \to \infty}{{F_1(X)}\over{F_2(X)}}=1$, one could show (if it is indeed the case) that the limit of the ratio of each corresponding individual term is 1.  For example if $F_1(X)=\sum_{k=1}^n {c_k x_k^2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sum_{i=k+1}^{n} {c_{ki} x_k x_i}$ and $F_2(X)=\sum_{k=1}^n {d_k x_k^2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sum_{i=k+1}^{n} {d_{ki} x_k x_i}$, then showing  $\lim_{n \to \infty}{{c_i}\over{d_i}}=1$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}{{c_{ij}}\over{d{ij}}}=1$ $\forall i,j$ would suffice.  (Again, assuming that is actually the case.  That requires just a bit of algebra.

Comment: @JimBaldwin, the method you proposed is actually what I did for my last paper which is still under review. To some extent, I feel it is enough for the current problem by comparing the coefficients asymptotically. This morning I just finished comparing $c_{k}$ and $d_{k}$ terms in your symbols. But one thing worth notice is that $ i,j$ plays a role in $c_{k}$ and $d_{k}$. Since in cases that, for example, $i=n-2, j=n-1$, $i$ and $j$ play a role in the process as n goes to $\infnity$. (I just realize this until this problem). But it is doable since dominant terms among $a0^2,a1a0,a1^2$ are same.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding.  Both $c_k$ and $d_k$ depend on only a single index and not two ($i$ and $j$).  It would seem that there are maybe only a few cases to consider for $F_1$: [$i=j$], [$i=1$ and $j=2$], [$i=n-1$ and $j=n$], [$i=j+1$], [$i+1=j$], and [$i\neq j$].  (I haven't written those mutually exclusive but the point is that there should be just a few cases to consider.)  If this discussion might this be better in Chat or through e-mail, that's fine for me.

Comment: @JimBaldwin, thx Jim. I do not know how to use chat function for now. But I present partial answer to the question in the answer session of this problem. Still left for me to rearrange $x_{k}x_{i}$ in the first formula.

Answer (score 1):

The formulas for the coefficients $d_{ki}$ for $F_2(X)$ were presented at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102454/how-could-i-expand-the-formula-in-terms-of-x-i2-and-x-ix-j-using-ma/102478#102478.  Those are as follows:

$d_{ki}={{-2}\over{n^2}} a_0^2+({{2}\over{n^2}}-{{4(k+i)}\over{n^3}})a_0 a_1 +
({{4k}\over{n^3}}-{{8ki}\over{n^4}})a_1^2$

The corresponding coefficients $c_{ki}$ for $F_1(X)$ (using a bit of summation algebra) are as follows:

$c_{ki}={{-2}\over{n^2}} a_0^2+({{2}\over{n^2}}-{{4(k+i-1)}\over{n^3}})a_0 a_1 
 + ({{2(2k-1)}\over{n^3}}-{{2(1-2k-2i+4k i)}\over{n^4}})a_1^2$

And both sets of coefficients need to be divided by $n$.

Comment: could you leave me with your email address? thx

Answer (score 0):

@JimBaldwin, For the problem of index i, you are correct.
Today I compared $ c_{k} $ with $d_{k} $ , the coefficients of squared terms $X_{k}^{2}$. With the help of Jim and careful rearrangement, we have

$c_{k}$=$(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2})a_{0}^{2}+(\frac{2k}{n^2}+\frac{2-4k}{n^3})a_{0}a_{1}+(\frac{k^2+k-1}{n^3}+\frac{-4k^2+4k-1}{n^4})a_{1}^{2}$;

$d_{k}$=$(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2})a_{0}^{2}+(\frac{2k+2}{n^2}+\frac{-4k}{n^3})a_{0}a_{1}+(\frac{k^2+3k}{n^3}+\frac{4k^2}{n^4})a_{1}^{2}$;

It can be shown that that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_{k}X_{k}^{2}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}d_{k}X_{k}^{2}=o_{p}(1)$, under one of my assumption that $X=O_{p}(n^{\frac{1}{3}})$

Next step is left to show the same relationship holds for the cross terms. I am still trying to combine the cross term in $F_{1}(X)$ in terms of $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{i=k+1}^{n}c_{ki}X_{k}X_{i}$ in this elegant manner.